# Create dynamic Linq queries for XML

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to build a query builder where the user has the opportunity to input different where conditions like "ID > 10" "AND ID < 40".

Also the user can select different xml elements that he wants to display. For example he can select to display the ID element and the Code element.

I have two lists one for the where filters the user selects and one for the elements he wants to show. My problem is I don't know how to add a logical operator like "&&" and "||" to the linq where clause.

Also I do not know how to dynamically generate the select statement to include only the fields that the user selected.

Here is what I have so far :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var query = doc.Descendants("STUDENT");

// iterate through all the where conditions and add them to linq query
foreach(WhereConditions wcon in whereConditions)
{
    query = query.Where(x => (int)x.Element(wcon.SELECTEDFIELD) >   Int32.Parse(wcon.COMPARISONVALUE));
}

foreach(string selectedColumns in selectedFields)
{
    XElement x;

    x = doc.Root.Element("STUDENTS").Element("STUDENT");
    query = query.Select(x =>(new {selectedColumns = x.Element(selectedColumns).Value}));
}
```

Comment: How does the `WhereConditions` class look like? does it contain a property that indicate whether it is an "AND" or an "OR"?

Comment: How do you decide to "AND" or "OR" the conditions together?

Comment: The WhereConditions class has these properties of type string
1- SELECTEDFIELD  (for example id, code, grade etc)
2- COMPARISONVALUE (user inputed value in a textfield)
3- COMPOARSIONOPERATOR ( for example > ,< , like, = ,!=)
4- LOGICALOPERATOR ( wich holds the value && or || )

Comment: Can you show that class in code? What happens if some of the conditions have logical operator && and some of them have logical operation ||? Can you give an example?

Comment: the class is pretty straight forward 

        class WhereConditions
    {
        public string LOGICALOPERATOR { set; get; } //storers value && or ||
        public string SELECTEDFIELD { set; get; } //stores the field used to be compared for ecample id
        public string COMPARISONOPERATOR { set; get; } // stores the operator for examle '>' , '<' , '=', '!='
        public string COMPARISONVALUE { set; get; } // stores the value the selected field is compared to for example 10, 20 , 23 etc

        public WhereConditions()
        {
        }
    }

     }

Comment: @Yacoub Massad The user can generate multiple where conditions for example
where id = 1 
&& code >2 
&& age <3
|| name like ('mike')
I have to parse all this where conditions one by one using a list of objects and then add these conditions to the linq query